# Sounds like a motor running in my wall when the water is running

Tags: plumbing, valve, pressure

I’m in desperate need of advice. I started having a vibration in my pipes that sounded like a motor in my wall any time any water was running in my house. I checked the pressure and realized my pressure reducing valve has gone bad. I replaced it and for a few weeks I had no problems. It started again and when I checked a small leak had developed out of the side of the pressure reducing valve. I replaced that as I assumed it was a faulty piece. Now any time I turn on the main water cutoff to my house I can hear it start to run through and then it abruptly stops and kind of jolts the pipes. It completely shuts off on it’s own. What should I do next???

Comment: So you have replaced the PRV twice? And your actual problem is no water in the house, as the motor running sound was before you replaced it the first time? Ah, it came back. So is the water stopping or the noise stopping?  Please try to be clear and detailed to improve the odds of getting a useful answer. At what point or device does the water "completely shut off on its own?" Or is it the noise that stops? What does your pressure gauge show, and where is that located?

Comment: sounds like you installed something backward

Comment: The noise is what’s coming back. After I replaced the valve today when opened back the main water cutoff back up I could hear the water begin to flow through and then I could hear it abruptly stop and see the pipes jolt as the water stopped. The faucet I turned on the faucet to see if water was passing through and it started with decent pressure but rapidly lost all water pressure u til it was just a trickle. The gauge was reading 60 psi until the noise came back at which point the needle started bouncing around.

Comment: did you let air out of the whole house ? open all faucets

Comment: It sounds like water hammer as risked asks did you flow the faucets , also sometimes a small leak at a toilet can cause water hammer it is the pipes moving I have found some caused from very small leaks anchoring the pipes will stop it if they are accessible, try slightly reducing the pressure to see what f that helps.